# Permissions & Role patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, permissions

I am working on an app (MUD game API) and have started looking in to Role based permissions. I've done some searching (including on SO) and have not quiet found an answer that matches my particular question.

So I've seen Claim Based security and Users/Group based security. Since this is a Mud, there could potentially be several hundred Commands that the user enters through telnet. I thought about creating an IRole interface, implementing it for each Role the API supports. 3rd party developers can implement their own roles as well. Then providing each Role with a collection of Commands that they are allowed to use at server start up. Handing a reference to that role to the users based on authentication permissions. That seems like it introduces to much tight coupling between the commands and roles.

Another option was to use an attribute at the class level for Types implementing ICommand. Again, this sounds like to much tight coupling.

What happens if a 3rd party developer decides they want to implement a Role in between User and Admin (like "QuestEditor" for a role allowed to edit/create quests). The developer would have to either edit the commands to add the required attribute, or build a collection in the constructor of the Role of all commands it can use. If a new command is introduced, then all roles have to be updated which is a pain.

I also thought about a relational implementation, where roles are related through a hierarchy. So I can specify that a Command is required to have a minimum role of "QuestEditor" but any role related *up* the hierarchy is allowed to use the command as well, but not any role related *down* the hierarchy. This allows Admins to use the command without editing their role, yet disallow StandardPlayer roles from using it. The issue is that every time a command is used, the hierarchy has to be crawled until the command finds the minimum role required. If QuestEditor is required, and the user is an admin, it can't infer that the user has the rights unless it crawls the hierarchy. I'm not sure that this is a big issue, but one down side.

I'm looking for input on what the best solution would be. I don't want to add update several hundred commands everytime a new role is created, nor do I want to update every role when a new command is created. I'd like something generic that can be used. If you could share your experience or any patterns that exist I'd appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/

Comment: @T.S. Thanks, we're actually using this pattern at my work. The problem I have with it for my particular side project is that it requires you to create an `activity` for each individual activity. I will have several hundred commands, each essentially being a unique activity. I could group some of them together into a single activity, but it still requires a lot of activities. Activities that I then have to turn around and supply to the user.

Comment: You can create a role base on activities. Basically, collection of activities can be a role. But then this is still going to be activity-based

Comment: I will probably group the activities in to Roles, just so I can assign a collection of activities to a user easily. Validating if a user can perform a command would still be done by hitting the Role.Activities property. After doing some whiteboarding, I don't think this will be as big of an issue as I originally thought. There will be several hundred commands, but they can all be grouped in to a series of 20-30 activities. Each command will be assigned an activity, and each user assigned Roles containing activities. If a new activity is created, I just add it to a handful of roles at most.

Comment: As an example, this particular Mud game shows a list of its commands. Each command would have an activity. For instance, for chat commands there are 9 different commands. `Say, Gossip, Message, Auction, Broadcast` etc. All of these commands could be assigned a `Chat Activity`. Then, all of the roles would have this activity assigned to it. If I come along and add a `GMSay command`, I can create a `GM Message` and assign it to the GM role. Instead of doing [Activity("SomeName")], does it make more sense to do [Activity(typeof(IActivity))]? Use an implementation instead of a string literal?

Comment: I forgot the Mud game showing a list of commands link: http://www.majormud.com/mudhelp_commands.html